# Select all same class elements and store in string

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I Have a page which has comments left by users, each post has has its own id which is stored in a hidden input tag, in order to dynamically get the latest posts I need to know the id's of all posts and place them in a string, each id needs to be separated by a comma.

for example...

**HTML markup**

```
<div class='msgPost'><div class='msgContainer'>
    <input class='activityId' type='hidden' value='579'>
    <span>
        <div class='name'>Bob</div>nm
    </span>
</div>

<div class='msgPost'><div class='msgContainer'>
    <input class='activityId' type='hidden' value='578'>
    <span>
        <div class='name'>Tom</div>4
    </span>
</div>

<div class='msgPost'><div class='msgContainer'>
    <input class='activityId' type='hidden' value='577'>
    <span>
        <div class='name'>John</div>123
    </span>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
function getLatestActivities(){
   var ignoreMessagesColl = $("input.activityId").val();

   $.ajax({
      traditional: true,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET", url: "include/process.php", 

      data:{
         getLatestActivity: "true",
         toUser: "4",
         ignoreMessages: ignoreMessagesColl
      },

      success: function(data){
         $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
            $('.commentMessage').after(elem.value);
         });              
      }
   });   
}
```

at the moment the variable **ignoreMessagesColl** only finds the first class instance of .activityid which has the value "579", but i actually need ignoreMessageColl to have the value "579, 578, 577"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`val` only returns the first one's value, try `map` plus `get` plus `join`:

```
var ignoreMessagesColl = $("input.activityId").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
```

What that does:

1. [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) loops through all of the matched elements and builds a jQuery-wrapped array of whatever the iterator function returns.
2. [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) gets the underlying array from the jQuery wrapper (I have no idea why `map` returns a jQuery wrapper).
3. [`join`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.5) combines the elements of the array into a string delimited with the given delimiter.

The end result for your example data is that `ignoreMessagesColl` will have `"579,578,577"`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. and thanks to everyone else who commented

Answer (score 2):

```
var values = [];    

$('.msgContainer input.activityId').each(function(){

    values.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: however that returns an array and not the desired comma seperated string

Comment: I appreciated your answer but like claarman stated I was going for a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should have:

```
var arr = [], str;
$("input.activityId").each(function(){
   arr.push(this.value);
});
str = arr.join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ignoreMessagesCol = $("input.activityId").map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(", ");
```

.map() will execute the inner anonymous function for every element in the selector and return a jQuery object collection. .get() will make it an array. .join() will make it a comma separated string